# How to implement custom navigation bar in android java as shown in images

Tags: java, android, user-interface, bottomnavigationview

Here is the design I want to implement in my app for bottom navigation bar.[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGldA.png)

After clicking another icon I want it to change as shown:[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsvRT.png)

I am new to android and so far I only know about the basic implementation of bottom navigation bar. I am unable to understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either you build the widget your self completely from scratch or you use already existing layouts and widgets to construct it.

**Building your own widget**
Creating your own widget can be quiet challenging depending on what you are trying to accomplish. You would have to create a class that extends View or any other subclass of it. For instance you might extend from LinearLayout since it might provide some of the functions you are looking for.
You'd have to at least

- overwrite the touch-events to create your own touch-handling
- overwrite the draw-methods to draw your custom ui
- overwrite the layout and measure-methods to adjust the layouts behavior when resizing etc.

This can become very complex, so i wouldn't recommend it for a beginner. While it allows for full customization of your widget it also comes with a higher risk of self inflicted bugs or unwanted behavior.

**Working with Layouts and Widgets**
Creating a widget like this using existing widgets and layouts is easy but has more limitations in what you an achieve. You would create a separate layout xml file in which you create the visuals of your widget. For the functional part you would write some kind of ui-controller class that implements all the required functions etc. for that layout and can be hooked up to it (using the existing callbacks of the views)

- Use IDs in your layout to access the different components that should have special behavior
- Implement a clicklistener or a touchlistener to handle the specific interaction events
- [For Animations Android provides an API](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview).
- Include your widgets layout xml into any other layout xml or inflate it separately. Then add your ui-controller

Android already provides a wide range of layouts and widgets that can be used to accomplish what you are looking for. I would utilize those before trying to write my own

Comment: could you please suggest some layouts and widgets which I could implement

Comment: @TusharRustagi For the base container you could use a LinearLayout. The round corners you can achieve by setting a drawable with round corners as its background. For icons you could use ImageViews. You need 2 drawables per icon. One for its active state (with the purple circle arround) and one for its inactive state. You set them in the onClick event. To move them up you can use a TranslateAnimation. For Text you can use a TextView which is invisible if the icon is inactive and becomes visible once the icon is active. The only event you need to override is the click event on the ImageViews